# Lucene: the file exists while canot get it by using the QueryParser

Tags: lucene

Basically I indexed 85k html files (google result pages and the key words are different university names), and i used the title of each page as  a field named "title" in my lucene index. When i searched key word like ***"duquesne AND university"*** , no result came out, however, when I changed the key word as ***"duquesne"*** only , i can get a result with title :"**title:Duquesne Univeristy - Google Search**"
Why did this happen? from the second try i can tell that this file with title Duquesne Univeristy is indexed but i cannot get it from the first try.
Many Thx!~

**Here's my code for building index, i used Jsoup for getting the title from web pages:**

```
//indexDir is the directory that hosts Lucene's index files 
     File   indexDir = new File("F:\\luceneIndex"); 

     Directory myindex=SimpleFSDirectory.open(indexDir);
     //dataDir is the directory that hosts the text files that to be indexed 
     File   dataDir  = new File("I:\\luceneTextFiles"); 
     Analyzer luceneAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT); 
     File[] dataFiles  = dataDir.listFiles(); 
     IndexWriterConfig indexConfig=new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT,luceneAnalyzer);
     IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(myindex, indexConfig); 
     long startTime = new Date().getTime(); 
     System.out.println("Total file number is  "+dataFiles.length+"");
     for(int i = 0; i < dataFiles.length; i++){ 
          if(dataFiles[i].isFile() && dataFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")){
               org.jsoup.nodes.Document t=Jsoup.parse(dataFiles[i], "UTF-8");                  
               Document document = new Document(); 
               Reader txtReader = new FileReader(dataFiles[i]); 
               document.add(new Field("title",t.title(),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
               document.add(new Field("path",dataFiles[i].getCanonicalPath(),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED)); 
               document.add(new Field("count",i+"",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
               document.add(new Field("contents",txtReader)); 
               indexWriter.addDocument(document); 

          } 
     } 

     //indexWriter.getCommitData();
     indexWriter.close(); 
     long endTime = new Date().getTime(); 

String queryKey="duquesne";
        String subqueryKey="university";
        String queryField="contents";
        String subqueryField="title";
        /*
         * 0------>normal search
         * 1------>range search
         * 2------>prefix search
         * 3------>combine search
         * 4------>phrase query
         * 5------>wild card query
         * 6------>fuzzy query
         */
        int querychoice=0;

        //initialize the directory
        File indexDir=new File("F:\\luceneIndex");
        Directory directory=SimpleFSDirectory.open(indexDir);
        IndexReader reader=IndexReader.open(directory);
        //initialize the searcher
        IndexSearcher searcher=new IndexSearcher(reader);
        Analyzer analyzer=new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);
        Query query;
        switch(querychoice){

        case 0:
            QueryParser parser=new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT,subqueryField,analyzer);
            query=parser.parse(queryKey);
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parsing `title:Duquesne Univeristy - Google Search` with standard analyzer will result in the query `title:duquesne defaultfield:univeristy defaultfield:google defaultfield:search` while the terms are OR-connected.

Comment: I dont get it my query is not **title:Duquesne Univeristy - Google Search**

Comment: O, you mean the analyzer i used then indexing ? Then should i use the WhiteSpaceAnalyzer instead? thx

Comment: the analyzer is ok I think, your problem with the "wrong" results is because your misunderstanding of your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, maybe because `university` search keyword and `Univeristy` are not the same words? Or did you misspell it in your question only?

Comment: I remember that the analyzer will automatically transform them into lower cases when indexing :-)

Comment: It's not about lowercasing but about misspelling: univeRSIty VS univeRIsty